# PowerShell: Can you write a class like the system ones?

Tags: powershell, class, namespaces

Hopefully a very simple question. I'm diving into classes within PowerShell; What I'm wondering is normally you estantiate a class as `Class <myClass> {}` is there a way to write it like the system ones `System.Collections.Generic....`. So it would be something akin to:
`class <myCompany>.<myClass> {}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NO

PowerShell classes cannot be namespaced with [native syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes), you'll need to compile your types from C# using [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type):

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
namespace MyCompany {
  public class MyClass { }
}
'@
```